# Execute postback url from another button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a two Buttons , buttonA (normal one ) and ButtonB  (has  postbackurl) , i need to execute (buttonB) from the click of ButtonA

```
<asp:button ID="ButtonA" runat="server"  text="Button" />
<asp:button ID="ButtonB" PostBackUrl="url" runat="server"  text="Button" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#<%= buttonA.ClientID%>").click(function(){
          $("#<%= buttonB.ClientID%>").trigger("click");
      });
  });
</script>
```

can someone tell me , how to do it , either with Jquery or codebehind , because really i don't know if it's possible ? 
Thanks,

Comment: That's possible...!  Do you get any error's on console ?

Comment: No ; but it didn't go to "URL"

Comment: Case sensitivity? Try ButtonA.ClientID and ButtonB.ClientID.

Comment: Yes - as far as I know JavaScript is case sensitive which is highly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are posting data from your form to ButtonB's `PostBackUrl`, I would just have the window redirect to the PostBackUrl like so:

```
<asp:button ID="ButtonA" runat="server"  text="Button" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#<%= buttonA.ClientID%>").click(function(){
          window.location.href = 'url';
      });
  });
</script>
```

There's no need to invoke a click event of another button just to do a redirect to a different location.

However, if you are indeed posting data with your form back to the server, you will need to do this:

```
<asp:button ID="ButtonA" runat="server"  text="Button" />
<asp:button ID="ButtonB" PostBackUrl="url" runat="server"  text="Button" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#<%= ButtonA.ClientID%>").click(function(){
          $("#<%= ButtonB.ClientID%>").click();
      });
  });
</script>
```